# Proper way to do this with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have two classes,

Image and Credit

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credit
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credit
end

class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has a field called name
  has_many :images
end
```

I want associate a Credit when Image is created, acting a bit like a tag. Essentially, I want behavior like Credit.find_or_create_by_name, but in the client code using Credit, it would be much cleaner if it was just a Create. I can't seem to figure out a way to bake this into the model.

Comment: A "Credit" is like a credit on a movie (attribution) as opposed to a credit on an account (payment), correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry. 2.5 years working in a newsroom has warped my jargon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credit

  attr_accessor :credit_name
  after_create { Credit.associate_object(self) }
end

class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has a field called name
  has_many :images

  def self.associate_object(object, association='images')
    credit = self.find_or_create_by_name(object.credit_name)
    credit.send(association) << object
    credit.save
  end
```

end

Then when you create an image what you can do is something like

```
Image.create(:attr1 => 'value1', :attr2 => 'value2', ..., :credit_name => 'some_name')
```

And it will take the name that you feed into the `:credit_name` value and use it in the `after_create` callback.

Note that if you decided to have a different object associated with Credit later on (let's say a class called `Text`), you could do still use this method like so:

```
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credit

  attr_accessor :credit_name
  before_create { Credit.associate_object(self, 'texts') }
end
```

Although at that point you probably would want to consider making a SuperClass for all of the classes that belong_to credit, and just having the superclass handle the association.  You might also want to look at [polymorphic relationships](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: That could work. But I'm hoping to put this logic in Credit, not Image, as eventually, many more things will have Credits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I thought you wanted the action to occur when an Image is created?  If you wanted to do it through credit then you could always create your images by doing something like `some_credit.images << Image.create(:attr1 => 'value1')` and then `some_credit.save` or something like that?

Comment: I want it to happen when ANYTHING creates a credit. There will eventually be a number of things with credits attached to them.

Comment: Your original question states: 'I want associate a Credit when Image is created'.  Please be clear, do you want a reaction to an `Image` being created or a reaction to a `Credit` being created?

Comment: Both. The Image creates the Credit when the Image is created, but I want the logic to happen on the credit side, so as I implement all the other things that have Credits, they get the same logic "for free".

Comment: It gives me some ideas. I'm still ideally looking for a solution that doesn't involve calling any special method from client code.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'client code'?  I don't understand what your ideal solution is here?  Can you please elaborate in more clear terms that an outside observer such as myself might be able to understand better?

Comment: e.g. code in Image. So Image can just do Credit.new(:name => "John Smith") and Image's credit association is setup with the appropriate Credit. Image doesn't know there is a bit of extra magic going on. This matters when you get into some of the Gems for auto-building admin sections, which just work with the low-level Model methods and  don't let you hook into the creation process.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more trouble than it's worth, and is dangerous because it involves overriding the `Credit` class's `initialize` method, but I think this might work.  My advice to you would be to try the solution I suggested before and ditch those gems or modify them so they can use your method.  That being said, here goes nothing:

First you need a way to get at the method caller for the Credit initializer.  Let's use a class [I found on the web called `CallChain`](http://grosser.it/2009/07/01/getting-the-caller-method-in-ruby/), but we'll modify it for our purposes.  You would probably want to put this in your `lib` folder.

```
class CallChain
  require 'active_support'

  def self.caller_class
    caller_file.split('/').last.chomp('.rb').classify.constantize
  end

  def self.caller_file(depth=1)
    parse_caller(caller(depth+1).first).first
  end

  private

  #Stolen from ActionMailer, where this was used but was not made reusable
  def self.parse_caller(at)
    if /^(.+?):(\d+)(?::in `(.*)')?/ =~ at
      file   = Regexp.last_match[1]
      line   = Regexp.last_match[2].to_i
      method = Regexp.last_match[3]
      [file, line, method]
    end
  end
end
```

Now we need to overwrite the `Credit` classes initializer because when you make a call to `Credit.new` or `Credit.create` from another class (in this case your `Image` class), it is calling the initializer from that class.  You also need to ensure that when you make a call to `Credit.create` or `Credit.new` that you feed in `:caller_class_id => self.id` to the attributes argument since we can't get at it from the initializer.

```
class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base 
  #has a field called name
  has_many :images
  attr_accessor :caller_class_id

  def initialize(args = {})
    super
    # only screw around with this stuff if the caller_class_id has been set
    if caller_class_id
      caller_class = CallChain.caller_class
      self.send(caller_class.to_param.tableize) << caller_class.find(caller_class_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Now that we have that setup, we can make a simple method in our `Image` class which will create a new `Credit` and setup the association properly like so:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :credit
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credit

  # for building
  def build_credit
    Credit.new(:attr1 => 'val1', etc.., :caller_class_id => self.id)
  end

  # for creating
  # if you wanted to have this happen automatically you could make the method get called by an 'after_create' callback on this class.
  def create_credit
    Credit.create(:attr1 => 'val1', etc.., :caller_class_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

Again, I really wouldn't recommend this, but I wanted to see if it was possible.  Give it a try if you don't mind overriding the `initialize` method on `Credit`, I believe it's a solution that fits all your criteria.